# How to program haskell with ghci?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I've been reading some material and here I have a question:
I saw a fragment of code is like this:

```
>getNthElem 1 xs = head xs
>getNthElem n [] = error "'n' is greater than the length of the list"
>getNthElem n xs
>    | n < 1     = error "'n' is non-positive"
>    | otherwise = getNthElem (n-1) (tail xs)
```

Should I type all these lines exactly the same into ghci or should I create a .hs file and put them in, then load it in the ghci?

Comment: I tried both of them before. The former one encountered an error that the ghci didn't recognize "="; while the latter one, doesn't it just make no sense that "getNthElem" occurs three times?

Comment: It does make sense. Try to start you Haskell adventure with some more basic statements.

Comment: I can recommend http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#ready-set-go

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this:

1. Use multiline mode within ghci by setting the flag as:

   ```
    Prelude> :set +m
    Prelude> let getNthElem 1 xs = head xs
    Prelude|     getNthElem n [] = error "error1"
    Prelude|     getNthElem n xs
    Prelude|                | n < 1 = error "error2"
    Prelude|                | otherwise = getNthElem (n-1) (tail xs)
    Prelude|
    Prelude>
   ```
2. Create a file and load it as a module to access the types and functions defined in it as

   ```
   Prelude> :l myModule.hs
   ```

   And file contents:

   ```
   getNthElem :: Int -> [a] -> a
   getNthElem 1 xs = head xs
   getNthElem n [] = error "'n' is greater than the length of the list"
   getNthElem n xs
                  | n < 1     = error "'n' is non-positive"
                  | otherwise = getNthElem (n-1) (tail xs)
   ```

I would recommend using the second option since it's quite easy to mess up indentation in multiline mode within GHCI. Also, make it a habit of adding type signatures before you start defining the function body.

Comment: I tried    :set +m but still received the error. How exactly should I do that? Thank you. :)

Comment: BTW how to type code using code style within comments?

Comment: If you put the `let` on its own line you don't need to indent the rest (because of GHC's `NondecreasingIndentation` extension), which may be easier for copy/paste. (That won't work with literate `>`s though.)

Answer (score 10):

You could write in 1 line:

```
> let getNthElem 1 xs = head xs; getNthElem n [] = error "'n' is greater than the length of the list"; getNthElem n xs | n < 1 = error "'n' is non-positive" | otherwise = getNthElem (n-1) (tail xs)
```

Don't forget to write semicolon instead of newline and add `let` word in the beginning.

You could also use multi-line regime:

```
> :{
| let getNthElem 1 xs = head xs
|     getNthElem n [] = error "'n' is greater than the length of the list"
|     getNthElem n xs
|       | n < 1     = error "'n' is non-positive"
|       | otherwise = getNthElem (n-1) (tail xs)
| :}
>
```

Answer (score 5):

The easiest thing is to create a file called e.g. `example.hs` and then start ghci at the command line and load the file

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> :load example.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main      ( example.hs, interpreted )
Ok, module loaded: Main.
*Main>
```

Alternatively you can load the file when you start ghci

```
$ ghci example.hs
GHCi, version 7.6.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
[1 of 1] Compiling Main      ( example.hs, interpreted )
Ok, module loaded: Main.
*Main>
```

Note that the `>` at the start of each line indicates that your file is a *literate Haskell* file i.e. it should have the extension *.lhs instead of *.hs. You should either rename your file to *.lhs or remove the `>` at the beginning of each line.

Comment: I'm still at the beginning so I have no idea what is a literate haskell file. Still thanks!

Comment: @user3928256 The default in a literate file is that the text is a comment, rather than source, and you have to specify where in the file your source code actually is.  It's usual to see a literate file where there's a lot more comments than code, and it lets you mix different formats, e.g. Markdown and Haskell, or ReST and Python so documentation generators have an easier time making nicely formatted docs.  In Haskell literate files, it's convention to either use `>` at the beginning of every line of code, or you can use the LaTeX style and wrap code blocks in `\begin{code}`-`\end{code}` tags.